# Binomial moment generating function

Tags: statistics, binomial-coefficients, moment-generating-functions

Hi I've got this question that I've been struggling with for hours.

$f(x)=\binom{r+x-1}{x}p^{r}(1-p)^{x}$

Show that:

$m_{x}(u)=E[e^{uX}]=(\frac{p}{1-(1-p)e^{u}})^{r}$

I've tried this so far:

$m_{x}(u)=E[e^{uX}]=\sum_{x=0}^{r+x-1}\binom{r+x-1}{x}e^{uX}p^{r}(1-p)^{x}$
$=\sum_{x=0}^{n}\binom{r+x-1}{x}p^{r}(e^{u}(1-p))^{x}$

But I get stuck here. Am I on the right track?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: What have you done yet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, The distribution is not binomial but negative binomial with parameter $p$ and $r$.

$$E(e^{uX}) = \sum\limits_{x=0}^{\infty} e^{ux} \binom{r+x-1}{x}p^r(1-p)^x = \sum\limits_{x=0}^{\infty}  \binom{r+x-1}{x}p^r(e^u(1-p))^x$$

Multiply and divided by the constant $(1-(e^{u}(1-p))^r$ and take $p^r$ out.

$$ E(e^{uX})= \frac{p^r}{(1-(e^{u}(1-p)))^r}\sum\limits_{x=0}^{\infty}  \binom{r+x-1}{x}(1-(e^{u}(1-p)))^r(e^{u}(1-p))^x$$

The summation equals to $1$ since it is the sum of the probability of each point in the sample space of the negative binomial distribution with parameter $(1-(e^{u}(1-p))$ and $r$.

$$E(e^{uX}) = \left(\frac{p}{(1-(e^{u}(1-p)))}\right)^r$$

Comment: Why did you multiply and divide by that constant?

Comment: Note that the last term in the first equation looks like the summation of probabilities of a new negative binomial distribution with parameter $p_1$ such that $1-p_1 = e^u(1-p) \implies p_1 = 1-e^u(1-p)$. Since $p^r$ is a constant term, I took it out and replaced it with $p_1^r$ by multiplying and dividing by $p_1^r$. This procedure reduced the summation to sum of probabilities of a new negative binomial distribution with parameter $p_1$ and by the axioms of probability, that summation is 1.